# Atom packages offlline

Tags: atom-editor, emmet

Yo uso atom con un proxy empresarial. He tratado de usar apm configurandole el proxy pero al parecer tengo restringido el acceso a ese host. Lo que hago para instalar un package es descargar el  codigo base de git-hub y copiarlo en el directorio ~.atom/packages/ hasta ahora me ha funcionado pero hay algunos paquetes que al parecer tienen dependencias y me dan error. como puedo solucionalr esto? Me pasa por ejemplo con emmet.

Comment: has visto las dependencias en git-hub? has probado a descargártelas primero? cuál es el error?

Comment: como comento abajo lo que hago con las dependencias es instalarlas con npm. me gustaria saber si puedo descargar las dependencias y pegarlas en algun directorio sin usar npm

Answer (score 1):

Ya conseguí hacerlo, después de copiar la carpeta del paquete en en directorio .atom/packages se debe instalar el paquete con npm, quien agrega las dependencias descritas en el package.json. Es decir hay abrir la consola en el directorio del paquete ej: .atom/packages/emmet-atom y escribir npm install.

> Despues que hice esto funcionó aunque npm de señaló advertencias. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo me dicen

Comment: si nos dices qué advertencias...